# Work with RDS Tags in boto3 / How to get ARN in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rds, boto3

I try to tag various objects in AWS using python. AFAIK it's not possible for some services using boto. Therefore, I decided to take a look at boto3. I've got stacked on the RDS. Based on the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.add_tags_to_resource%20documentation) the add_tags_to_resource method needs a resource ARN. I don't see a way to get it.

To address above problem I thought about creating  ARN on my own. After all it's not so hard -[RDS Tagging documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Tagging.html#USER_Tagging.ARN). But there is another problem. In my script I cannot guarantee to know account number, so I wonder how can I get account number to create ARN on my own.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder how can I get account number

Unfortunately it's not that easy to find. But you can have some hacks:

If you have access to certain API calls, you can get security group or AMI and check for an OwnerId.

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> client.describe_security_groups()['SecurityGroups'][0]['OwnerId']
'1234567890'
```

This trick will only work if you can guarantee that SG or AMI was created by the account that you are looking for.

#### OR

Use make an API call to the IAM and parse ARN of your own Role or User

```
>>> client = boto3.client('iam')
>>> client.get_user()['User']['Arn'].split(':')[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your boto3 to the latest version, it now returns a new attribute `DBInstanceArn`

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances

Answer (score 1):

Using boto3 you can get the db arn with this code....

```
from boto3 import client
REGION = "us-east-1"
INSTANCES = ["db-name-01"]

rds = client("rds", region_name=REGION)

if INSTANCES:
    for instance in INSTANCES:
        instance_counts = {}
        response = rds.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance)
        dbins = response['DBInstances']
        dbin = dbins[0]
        dbarn = dbin['DBInstanceArn']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rds arn from

`rds_dict = self.rds_client.describe_db_instances()`

if you iterate through `rds_dict` you will get a key named `DBInstanceArn`

i am using boto3 for this

Comment: As the question is five years old you should include version number to which your solution applies when posted.